# converting ArrayList to Array in jsp

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, arraylist

i'm trying to pass Resultset values from java to jsp using ArrayList

[image]

[image]

[image]

and converting ArrayList to Array im able to get the values but like this

[image]

i want the values like this [0,0,1,1,1,5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @[Scary Wombat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310289/scary-wombat) points out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59657729/10871900), JSTL is better suited in your case.

However, if you want to use JSP, you can do that to.

Your main problem is that `result` is a `List` of a `Map` and not just a `List`. You just output every `Map` in the `List`.

You call `.toArray` which returns an `Object[]`. I would recommand you to just iterate over the `List`:

```
for(int i=12;i<result.size;i++){}%><%=result.get(i);%><%}<%
```

With that, your output is the same but you can access the result as `Map` and not just as `Object`. If you want to get the integer, you can use `.get("jn");`

The code would be:

```
for(int i=12;i<result.size();i++){}%><%=result.get(i).get("jn")%><%}<%
```

You could also output the elements using java 8 streams:

```
%><%=result.stream().filter(map->map.get("jn")).collect(java.util.streams.Collectors.joining(","))%><%
```

Another possibility is just to create a `List<Integer>` and call `result.add(rs.getInt(3));`

Answer (score 2):

Better to use JSTL rather than java in your JSP files

Assuming the attribute is called `rs`

```
<c:forEach items="rs" var="value">
  <c:out value="${value}"/>
 </c:forEach>
```

Also see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm for usage on using JSTL

Comment: I think the problem id that it is a `List` of `Map`s. So you would have to call `${value.get("jn")}`.

Comment: @dan1st I was ignoring it, and just answered the question as per his title.  Looking at their code, I am not sure why they want such a strange data structure.  I think there will be a new question soon.

Answer (score -2):

Try this program. i hope resolve your problem

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


        List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        al.add(0); 
        al.add(0); 
        al.add(1); 
        al.add(1); 
        al.add(1); 
        al.add(5); 

        Integer[] arr = new Integer[al.size()]; 
        arr = al.toArray(arr); 

        for (Integer x : arr) 
            System.out.print(x + " ");
```

The output is:

```
0
0
1
1
1
5
```

Comment: First problem: The OP wants to do this in JSP. Second problem: as the comment shows, `al.toArray()` returns an `Object[]` and not an `Integer[]`. `al.toArray(new Integer[al.size()])` should be used instead.

Comment: And the OP even calls `al.toArray()`